# How to use a sum (case) into second table as condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my query:

```
    select matricule,nom_ligne,count(num_ticket) as nbre_ticket, sum(prix) as moant,receveur, nom_gie, 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN depense.id_bus = 1 THEN depense.montant ELSE 0 END) AS NbrARRNP from depense) as tot,
receveur, nom_gie from journal_recettes
group by matricule,nom_ligne,receveur, nom_gie
```

And I obtain this results: 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGd1Q.jpg)
But what I need is to use this condition :

```
CASE WHEN depense.id_bus = journal_recettes.id_bus THEN depense.montant ELSE 0 END
```

But When I try, i obtain this error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGcD.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error as plain (formatted) text. No screen shots please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider modifying your query like below by joining both tables on `id_bus` column

```
select j.matricule,
j.nom_ligne,
count(j.num_ticket) as nbre_ticket, 
sum(j.prix) as moant,
j.receveur, 
j.nom_gie, 
SUM(d.id_bus) AS NbrARRNP
from journal_recettes j
join depense d on d.id_bus = j.id_bus
group by j.matricule,
j.nom_ligne,
j.receveur, 
j.nom_gie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a correlated subquery.  This is usually handled in the `where` clause:

```
select matricule, nom_ligne, count(num_ticket) as nbre_ticket,
       sum(prix) as moant, receveur, nom_gie, 
       (select SUM(d.montant) AS NbrARRNP
        from depense d
        where d.id_bus = jr.id_bus
       ) as tot,
       receveur, nom_gie
from journal_recettes jr 
group by matricule, nom_ligne, receveur, nom_gie;
```

In this case, you may have an issue because the correlation condition is not a `group by` key.  I'm not sure if Postgres supports this construct.  If this is a problem, the simplest solution is to include `id_bus` in the `group by`, but without sample data, I'm not sure if that works in this case.

Comment: GReat,just let add the NbrARRNP field on group by line to let it work correctly. I test it and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing the join on id_bus, you can use Common Table Expressions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html)

```
 with sums as  (SELECT id_bus, sum(CASE
             WHEN depense.id_bus = 1 THEN depense.montant
             ELSE 0
           END) AS NbrARRNP
    FROM   depense
    group by id_bus) 
 SELECT matricule,
       nom_ligne,
       Count(num_ticket) AS nbre_ticket,
       Sum(prix)         AS moant,
       receveur,
       nom_gie,
       d.NbrARRNP AS tot,
       receveur,
       nom_gie
FROM   journal_recettes j left outer join sums d on j.id_bus = d.id_bus
GROUP  BY matricule,
      nom_ligne,
      receveur,
      nom_gie,
      j.id_bus
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all.
I post my final solution to contribute :

```
select p1.matricule,p1.nom_ligne,
Count(p1.num_ticket) as nbre_ticket, Sum(p1.prix) as montant, 
(select sum(montant) as tot from depense p2
where date_trunc('day',p2.date_depense) = date_trunc('day',p1.date_vendu)  
group by date_depense) som_depense  ,
(Sum(p1.prix) -((select sum(montant) as tot from depense p3
where date_trunc('day',p3.date_depense) = date_trunc('day',p1.date_vendu)  
group by date_depense) ) ) net_reverse ,to_char(p1.date_vendu,'YYYYMMDD'),
p1.receveur, p1.nom_gie, id_line
    from journal_recettes p1
    group by 
    matricule,nom_ligne, date_vendu,receveur,nom_gie, id_line
```

And it's work as well.